# Laravel 5 update returns the old relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a **"belongsTo"** relation.

```
public function relation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Relation', 'relation_id');
}
```

When I create an instance everything works as expected. It is returned the new instance including the relation.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $instance = $this->model->create($request->all());

    return $instance;
}
```

When I update the **"relation_id"** It returns the old relation. It is not returned immediatly.

```
public function findOrFail($id)
{
    $link = $this->model
        ->with('relation')
        ->findOrFail($id);

    return $link;
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $instance = $this->findOrFail($id);

    $instance->update($request->all());

    //$instance = $instance ->fresh();

    return $instance ;
}
```

Seems that using **$instance->fresh()** or removing **->with('relation')** the new relation is returned immediatly in the current instance.

I am wondering why it does not return the new relation immediatly as it does for **create**.

Answer (score 0):

`create()` function returns instance see [API DOC on `create()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_create)
`update()` returns `bool` see [API DOC on `update()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_update)

After update you **need to reload relation** using [load()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_load) or [fresh()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fresh) as you stated.

> You only update current model / table not any relationships bound to it.

---

<strike>Most likely you are missing (or have incorrect) `$fillable` array in your model. Which protects you against "mass-assignment" vulnerability.</strike>

Read more on topic in documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment).

> A mass-assignment vulnerability occurs when a user passes an unexpected HTTP parameter through a request, and that parameter changes a column in your database you did not expect. For example, a malicious user might send an is_admin parameter through an HTTP request, which is then passed into your model's create method, allowing the user to escalate themselves to an administrator.

---

Tip:

Do not use `$request->all()`, instead use `$request->only(['name', 'age'])` now its explicitly using only `name` and `age` parameters. I know its not DRY, because you have to keep `$fillable` in sync with `->only` array, but anyone new to the code will know right from controller what is going on.